# MP3 playback with dynamic tempo adjustment

Tags: audio, mp3, playback, tempo

I need to whip up a quickie app, something quick and dirty, on windows that lets a user control the tempo of a playing mp3 file with a slider.

Any recommendations on libraries/programming languages/controls that can make this easy?

I don't have control over the media choice (has to be mp3) or the platform (has to be windows)

Edit:  Actually, I can convert the files to whatever format is necessary.

Comment: Does the pitch have to remain constant or can it fluctuate with the speed changes?

Comment: I am open to any languages.  I'm pretty comfortable with them all but would prefer a quicker scripting option over c/c++ or java.  I'm thinking it will probably end up being a dotnet app.

Comment: Ryan, I am not knowledgeable about sound so I don't know.  I was asked to whip something up for a researcher to let people estimate the tempo of something they heard by listening to a file and adjusting it so my guess is that the pitch would have to be constant or it would be another cue.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Media Player v10+ has this built in. [Take a look here.](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/howto/PlayFaster_how_to.aspx) Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Sweet! I never knew that WMP could do that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That's cool but what I need is to be able to manage it programmatically (embed in an app, randomize the initial tempo and record the users selected tempo) so I need to know how to get at it via WMP's API.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [this.](http://www.codeproject.com/cs/media/cswavplay.asp?df=100&forumid=13779&exp=0&fr=26&select=736865)

---

**Edit:** The [WinMM.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713771(VS.85).aspx) has a function called [waveOutSetPlaybackRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713761(VS.85).aspx) ([P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.waveOutSetPlaybackRate)) which might be helpful as this DLL (which has been included with windows since Win 9x) can play MP3's. [Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/code111_Play-MP3-Files-Using-Csharp.html) is some basic info on how to play the sounds using C#.

Answer (score 0):

So far this is what I have found:

[2xAV™  Plug-In For Windows Media Player®](http://www.enounce.com/products/ms/wmp/2xav/usersguide.php#Plug-InUsersGuide)

Ideally, I would prefer something open source but if I can't find other options I'll give this a go.